# Nightwatch - Meaning of WaitForElementVisible and WaitForElementPresent

Tags: nightwatch.js

Im **using Nightwatch for e2e and Im finding these two command a little bit confusing** given the name and explanation that comes with them.

**.waitForElementVisible:**
*Waits a given time in milliseconds for an element to be visible in the page before performing any other commands or assertions.*

What is the meaning of **visible**?

- An element position in the footer, you need to scroll to see it, is it considered visible?
- Does it mean visible in the DOM even if it is `display:hidden`, `position:relative; left:20000px;`, ...? Not actually visible for a user but dom is existing basically.
- What is a modal view in on top of some content? Is it visible?

**.waitForElementPresent:**
*Waits a given time in milliseconds for an element to be present in the page before performing any other commands or assertions.*

What is the meaning of **present**?

- Existing in the DOM without taking into account if it's visible or not?

**Is there any relation/implication between these two command?**

- If an element return truth for **.waitForElementVisible** does it imply that **.waitForElementPresent** will return true?

A lot of questions but maybe an explanation about how they work would solve all of these small questions...

Sometimes Im just getting errors and Im thinking that it might be my bad understanding of these two commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is problem with definition ? You already answer your question.

> An element position in the footer, you need to scroll to see it, is it considered visible?

- No,you dont need to scroll to check it visible or not.May be you do need with some command but not with these visible/present commands.

> Does it mean visible in the DOM even if it is display:hidden, position:relative; left:20000px;, ...? Not actually visible for a user but dom is existing basically.

- Yes,it exists(means present) in the DOM but for some reason it is not visible yet
  (bad connection,attribute value,...).

> If an element return truth for .waitForElementVisible does it imply
>   that .waitForElementPresent will return true?

- yes it will, if an element is visible = > it is present.

For usage , you can check out my an example answer here,it might help .

[Login timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309959/nightwatch-page-object-persistence/37326675#37326675)

Comment: This answer is just as unclear as the nightwatch.js docs, but what I'm getting from this is |
.waitForElementPresent  - means present in the DOM tree | .waitForElementVisible - means present in the DOM tree and visible by the user in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Basically an element might be present (as in loaded in DOM) but not visible (e.g. out of view so you might need to scroll to see it, or it might be hidden).

If you want to perform an action like a click on an element then you want to be using 'visible'.